# Do we want an image of the week competition?

Tags: discussion

I'm in two minds about this, so open it to suggestions.

Would an AI-generated image of the week competition be useful or wanted?
Similar to Photography.SE's [Photo of the week](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition)

Of course it needn't be weekly.  It could be monthly or an occasional one-off competition, similar to the [Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/image-competition-finishes-end-of-february-2023) (which is on their meta site, not a bad idea in itself)

This is not just to show off what can be produced.  If images are posted along with which AI was used to create them and what prompts were used, then it could help other users learn how to create better images.  It could become a learning resource, not merely a gallery.

Each competition could have a theme, to try to keep some sensible means of comparison.

I'm aware that this would be a workload for the moderators.  Would they be up for it?

Comment: I love the idea provided it doesn't add too much bookkeeping work.

Comment: Arqade also has similar for videogame screenshots. I think it'd be great to try on GenAI. Photography's contest does seem to have been on hold for over a year now. Their last contest ("Reflections" from June 2022) got 30 submissions, so it doesn't look to be lack of interest, but rather due to it being [a manual process maintained by one moderator](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7265).

Comment: Issue: moderation. I don't want to see an image of a character from a pegi-12 well know videogame getting removed again. You may have to be VERY careful with the posted pictures. Site has inconsistent standards: just look at the anime chatboard.

Answer (score 1):

> Would an AI-generated image of the week competition be useful or wanted?

It would be useful when accompanied by the tool, prompts, and configurations/parameters that the image was generated from.

Do I want it? No. I do not want to see random images in the landing page of GenAI site even if it is selected as the best of [any period]. I feel like it is an advertisement of some sort. This is not entirely image or graphic intensive site like [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) or [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). GenAI tools are currently capable of generating texts, images, audio, videos, and maybe some other things that I do not know of at the moment. So, you see there are many other elements that are parts of our focus; otherwise, there should as well be best text, best audio, best video, and etc. apart from the best image.

With that being said, if the competition is really gonna happen and its result does not show at the front page then I will not be so negative about it.

> I'm aware that this would be a workload for the moderators. Would they be up for it?

Well, this really depends on the moderators. I am not one, so I can't answer this for you.

Comment: I understand that when people say "moderators," they typically mean "community moderators." However, I would like to address two points regarding your statement that you are not a moderator. Firstly, the public Q&A platform was created with the idea that the community would handle most moderation tasks. This is why the reputation system grants moderation privileges based on a user's reputation. Secondly, we should not place all responsibility for fostering a sense of community on community moderators. People having moderation privileges should be confident to say "I'm a moderator".

Answer (score 0):

> Do we want an image of the week competition?

I wouldn't phrase it as a competition. No need to turn everything into a competition.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Just have some minimal standards for reproducing the artwork (model name, prompt) - but I wouldn't mandate it to be complete (can get complicated or involve randomness).